# Tcp port forwarding in Google cloud to gke cluster

Tags: networking, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am fairly experienced with kuberenetes but very new to Google cloud. I have an haproxy-ingress controller running with nodeports of 30080 30443. I need to have a static IP that can forward port 80 and 443 to those ports with proxy protocol to all nodes in the cluster. Preferably with a tcp health check to bring nodes in and out.  What are the basic pieces I should create for this?

Answer (score 2):

To have a static IP that can forward port 80 and 443 you would have to [reserve an IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address). Once you have a reserved IP address you can use it for your GKE configuration. I have found [this GitHub article](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce#frontend-https) which describes a similar scenario.

I have also found a youtube video on "[The ins and outs of networking in Google Container Engine and Kubernetes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2bhV81MfKQ&feature=youtu.be)" from Google Cloud Next '17. In this video, it describes how to expose the service (the discussion that begins at around 38:00). This is where they get into exposing the service. The infrastructure knows how to treat the 'loadBalancer' tag (mentioned at 40:20) and automatically creates the forwarding rules.

The command for that in the gcloud shell is described at https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstart, namely.

kubectl expose deployment hello-server --type LoadBalancer \ 
--port 80 --target-port 8080

This creates a forwarding rule with a public IP that can be returned with; 
$ kubectl get service hello-server

This should also show up in the output of; 
$ gcloud compute forwarding-rules list